# What does the '${var// /+}' mean in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have never seen the following shell script syntax:

```
cpu_now=($(head -n 1 /proc/stat))
cpu_sum="${cpu_now[@]:1}"
cpu_sum=$((${cpu_sum// /+}))
```

Can anyone explain what the `${cpu_sum// /+}` mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the same as `$cpu_sum`, but with all occurrences of  (a space) being replaced by `+`. (See [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Answer (score 4):

```
cpu_sum=$((${cpu_sum// /+}))
```

It is actually 2 step operation:

1. First all the spaces are being replaced by `+` in `${cpu_sum// /+}`
2. Then using `$((...))` **arithmetic addition** is being performed for adding all the numbers in `$cpu_sum` variable to get you aggregate sum.

**Example:**

```
# sample value of cpu_sum
cpu_sum="3222 0 7526 168868219 1025 1 357 0 0 0"

# all spaced replaced by +
echo ${cpu_sum// /+}
3222+0+7526+168868219+1025+1+357+0+0+0

# summing up al the values and getting aggregate total
echo $((${cpu_sum// /+}))
168880350
```